# Buttons got lock again after unlocking another button

Tags: android, save, android-sqlite

I am having issue regarding the buttons. After succeeding unlocking level 2 based on reaching the score from playing Level 1. I proceed to test Level 2 and ensure it can unlock Level 3 based on the score requirement, however, after succeed in unlocking Level 3. Level 2 become lock again. I am really not sure what went wrong. I may have got my logic wrong or something. It should had already remain enabled(true) after the Level 2 button had been set to enabled true. I will show my code related. Anyone who knows the answer please guide me.

This is in the LevelPage activity where it contains all the Level buttons for the user to choose which level to play, i will show just the relevant since the code in this activity is too long.

```
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(LevelPage.this);
    HashMap<String,String> data = db.getData();
    final String level1Score = data.get("LEVEL1");
    final String level2Score = data.get("LEVEL2");
    final String level3Score = data.get("LEVEL3");
    final String level4Score = data.get("LEVEL4");

    btnLevel1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickSound.start();
            Intent intent = new Intent(LevelPage.this, Level1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    if (level1Score != null && level1Score.equals("30")) {
        btnLevel2.setEnabled(true);
    btnLevel2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                clickSound.start();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LevelPage.this, Level2.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    } else {
        btnLevel2.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if (level2Score != null && level2Score.equals("35")) {
        btnLevel3.setEnabled(true);
        btnLevel3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickSound.start();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LevelPage.this, Level3.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    } else {
        btnLevel3.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

This is the Level2 page where the user plays the game and ensure to score 35 points to unlock:

```
else if (score == 35) {
                DBHelper db = new DBHelper(Level2.this);
                db.saveData(2,"35");
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(Level2.this);
                builder.setTitle("Level 2 Complete!");
                builder.setMessage("You have won! You have unlock level 3! 
You can proceed to Level 3 or go back.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Unlock", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Level2.this, 
LevelPage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
```

This is the SQLite Database to save and get the score data:

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Level";
 private static final String USERTABLE = "USER_INFO";
 private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
 private static final String LEVEL1 = "LEVEL1";
 private static final String LEVEL2 = "LEVEL2";
 private static final String LEVEL3 = "LEVEL3";
 private static final String LEVEL4 = "LEVEL4";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + USERTABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + LEVEL1 + " TEXT,"
        + LEVEL2 + " TEXT,"
        + LEVEL3 + " TEXT,"
        + LEVEL4 + " TEXT " + ");";

/*private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + USERTABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + LEVEL1 + " TEXT,"
        + LEVEL2 + " TEXT"+");"; */

private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USERTABLE;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
}

//to save score in db according to the level
public void saveData(int level,String score){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
    switch(level){
        case 1:
            data.put(LEVEL1, score);
            break;
        case 2:
            data.put(LEVEL2,score);
            break;
        case 3:
            data.put(LEVEL3,score);
            break;
        case 4:
            data.put(LEVEL4,score);
            break;
    }
    db.insert(USERTABLE,null,data);
    db.close();
}


//to get score from db
//you can modify this function if you want to get score for a specific level
public HashMap<String,String> getData(){
    HashMap<String,String> scoreMap = new HashMap<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + USERTABLE ;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            scoreMap.put(LEVEL1,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LEVEL1)));
            scoreMap.put(LEVEL2,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LEVEL2)));
            scoreMap.put(LEVEL3,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LEVEL3)));
            scoreMap.put(LEVEL4,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LEVEL4)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return scoreMap;

}
```

Note: The same also applies to Level 3 and Level 4. Even after Level 4 is unlock, Level 3 also got lock again along with Level 2. The result keep on repeating where it unlock next Level but lock the previous Level all of a sudden

To put SharedPrefences:

```
 else if (score == 30) {
                /*DBHelper db = new DBHelper(Level1.this);
                db.saveData(1,"30"); */
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
 AlertDialog.Builder(Level1.this);
                builder.setTitle("Level 1 Complete!");
                builder.setMessage("You have won! You have unlock level 2! You can proceed to Level 2 or go back.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Unlock", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Level1.this, LevelPage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.show();
                runTimer.cancel();
            }
```

Comment: It is because you are adding the score of each level in the new row so other columns except unlocked level have an empty string value.

Comment: Which part am i adding the score of each level? May i know how to solve that part? Sorry, i am new to programming and i received from a guy who helped me along the way

Comment: saveData() method in `DBHelper` class. `db.insert()` method adds new row in database.

Comment: to solve ur problem use shared preferences in android

Comment: Is it ok for you to provide me the solution? i dont know how to do the part. Just one example for a level will do. The rest i will know what to do.

Comment: sure I will give you the overview for implementing shared preference.

Comment: Even though i am using SQL Database, but may i know why to use shared preferences? About the `db.insert()`, what should i do with that in saveData() method?  I should put db.insert(data) after the data.put and before the break?

Comment: shared preference is easy to use and best fit for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an overview of SharedPreference that can be used in our case.
Write Level score to SharedPreference:
Your saveData() method will look like this.

```
public void saveData(String level, int score) {
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("score.xml",
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(level, score); editor.commit();
}
```

Reading from SharedPreference:

```
public int getLevelScore(String level) {
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("score.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int levelScore = sharedPref.getInt(level, defaultScoreForLevel);
return levelScore;
}
```

You can get more information about SharedPreference [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).
**Edit:**

```
final String level1Score = getLevelScore("LEVEL1");
final String level2Score = getLevelScore("LEVEL2");
final String level3Score = getLevelScore("LEVEL3");
final String level4Score = getLevelScore("LEVEL4");
```

Call saveData() method whenever user scores.

Comment: Oh, its still possible to use SharedPrefences inside a SQLite DB method? That is something new.

Comment: No...you don't need sql to store such simple data. Why to do such complex things when answer is very simple and easy. Just modify your code to use SharedPrefs.

Comment: Hmm, so i just need to put that code about saveData() in the Level2 and other level activity. And then in LevelPage, it will read SharedPreference?

Comment: Because i need to put that SharedPreference code in the else statement of the score. I will show you my code for that part

Comment: In LevelPage use ` getLevelScore(String level)` method to get the score of any level you want and then perform your check to unlock next level.

Comment: Check above about the Shared Preference part. I should be putting Shared Preference code in the else statament of the score is 30. Instead of calling another public void saveData method()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148719/discussion-between-mobile-developer-and-murali-prajapati).